# Droplines in 3D plot using plotly in R?

Tags: r, plot, graph, 3d, plotly

I am trying to make vertical lines from the points to the x-y axis on a 3D plot using plotly. This seems important for readability of 3D graphs, which otherwise look great with plotly, but I can't find how to do this anywhere after a lot of searching.

For example, when using scatterplot3d(), this can be done by simply adding the line ***type="h"*** like in this example:

```
library(scatterplot3d)
with(mtcars, {
  scatterplot3d(disp, wt, mpg,           # x y and z axis
                color="blue", pch=19,    # filled blue circles
                type="h",                # lines to the horizontal plane
                main="3-D Scatterplot Example",
                xlab="Displacement (cu. in.)",
                ylab="Weight (lb/1000)",
                zlab="Miles/(US) Gallon")
})
```

But plotly looks so much better and is more versatile than scatterplot3d().... Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from Carson Sievert on the plotly community forum, in case anyone is interested. After programming the function group2NA() (copy and paste from https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/blob/master/R/group2NA.R), the following will do the job, though a little clunky:

```
library(plotly)

mtcars$id <- seq_len(nrow(mtcars))
ms <- replicate(2, mtcars, simplify = F)
ms[[2]]$mpg <- 0
m <- group2NA(dplyr::bind_rows(ms), "id")

plot_ly(color = I("black"), showlegend = F) %>%
  add_markers(data = mtcars, x = ~disp, y = ~wt, z = ~mpg) %>%
  add_paths(data = m, x = ~disp, y = ~wt, z = ~mpg)
```